# How to count record that match with a description based off a field that is a limit

Tags: ms-access, limit

Below is a snip from my table where multiple FC descriptions are counted over the same date span.

[image]

I was running Total Statistic Analyzer for this data and got the table below which has an upper limit connected to each FC desciption.

[image]
[image]

I want a text box on a form to show the count of how many dates for that FC description are above that upper limit from the query.

Comment: Please show the code that you are having a problem with.

Comment: I don't see FC description in table with UpperLimit field.

Comment: @June7 Sorry I should of mentioned that the 2 and 3 picture are the same query just different screen shots of columns in the query.

Comment: Then try joining these two datasets and building aggregate query with filter criteria.